# Class 'EaDesign_PdfGenerator_Helper_Data not found

Tags: php, magento

I am very new to magento, I am trying to install "Invoice PDF generator" extension. I installed it through the magento connect, after pressing install button I got message like "Clear cache successfully".

After this message I pressed refresh button and then return to admin link. But after clicking on that link I am facing fatal error like

> Class 'EaDesign_PdfGenerator_Helper_Data not found in E:\wamp\www\leeveNew\app\Mage.php on line 547

Can anybody please tell me if I done anything wrong and suggest any solution for it.

Note : My magento version is 1.9.0.1.

Comment: check EaDesign/PdfGenerator/Helper/Data.php exist or not?

Comment: @DRAJI, thanks for replying. It's present. Can you please tell me how to remove extension manually(not from admin panel) because my admin panel only show this error and logout button not any other on dashboard. I will try to install it again.

Comment: you need to disable extension from app/etc/modules/ then you need to remove var/cache folder then try in admin panel will work.

Comment: @Empiro Techonologies, thanks for reply and your solution it resolves my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For working extension, disable compilation, and enable extension again....

Answer (score 1):

you need to disable extension from app/etc/modules/ then you need to remove var/cache folder then try in admin panel will work.